# Flutter desktop MacOS - Unable to create FlutterView

Tags: xcode, flutter, macos, dart, desktop-application

Latest Flutter stable, version 3.7 on MacOS. Hello world application (created with `flutter create` command). Everything is fine on iPhone and web (Chrome). But if I try to `flutter run macOS`, I'm getting error:

[image]

and empty window displayed.

```
 ~ % flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.0, on macOS 13.1 22C65 darwin-x64, locale
    pl-PL)
    • Flutter version 3.7.0 on channel stable at
      /usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/3.7.0/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision b06b8b2710 (7 days ago), 2023-01-23 16:55:55 -0800
    • Engine revision b24591ed32
    • Dart version 2.19.0
    • DevTools version 2.20.1

[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from:
      https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK
      components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup
      for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
      `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.


[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14C18
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from
      https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup
      for detailed instructions).

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-x64     • macOS 13.1 22C65 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 109.0.5414.119

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I have the same issue. Are you running it on real Apple hardware or in a VM on a Windows Box?

Comment: They removed OpenGL for MacOS so it is looking for hardware to run die graphics. It you are using a VM then it wont work.

Comment: I'm running MacOS on qemu on Linux box. Of course, there's no hw accelerated graphic support, but most apps have no problem with that.

Comment: They removed OpenGL in version 3.7.0. I works if you use 3.3.10.

Comment: Here they said they would remove it https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/108304 And now it is removed.

Comment: This s*cks big time, I have MacOs running with OpenCore on a PC which runs great. There are many people with Vm's or thelike who develop for Macos or iOs.

Comment: It seems, this is just when building for MacOs, building for iOs works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Flutter won't work in VMs anymore as they have removed OpenGL support in version 3.7.0 https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/108304

Comment: Only when building for MacOs, Build for iOs works.